# Lync presence indicators not working when dynamically added

Tags: javascript, presence-indication, lync

I am working on a Lync presence Indicator in Sharepoint.

I have read this [Article](http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/lync-presence-indicators-code-snippets-in-sharepoint-2013/) for adding presence indicator and it works fine if I add HTML static. But when I add HTML Dynamically it doesn't work anymore. I would wants to know why this not work when dynamically added?

I have also tried to add HTML through console. But this also does not work.

Here is my code which I am adding dynamically.

```
html += "<span class='ms-imnSpan'><a href='#' onclick='IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;' class='ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink'><span class='ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10'><img name='imnmark' title='' ShowOfflinePawn='1' class='ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32' src='/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23' alt='User Presence' sip='kaushal.khamar@xxxxx.com' id='imn_1,type=sip' /></span></a></span>";
```

I have gone through this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637915/adding-presence-indicator-to-a-custom-web-part) but it's not a solution.

Does the presence indicator work if I add this HTML dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

If you create the DOM dynamically, you have to call IMNRC function with the correct parameters:

```
IMNRC('user-sip', domelement)
```

In your case you should execute this after creating the DOM:

```
IMNRC('kaushal.khamar@xxxxx.com', document.getElementById('imn_1,type=sip'));
```